# Color mouse movement

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, mouseevent

I am currently working on a GUI Project with Qt C++. A part of my work consists of tracking the mouse movement and marking its position with a green pixel. The tracking should occur only on a certain image, which is stored in a label.

So far, the tracking of the mouse has worked fine and I have been able to extract the coordinates from the QMouseEvent. However, I seem to have difficulties coloring the pixel the mouse is on. What I want is just a colored pixel which marks continuously where the mouse is, but I'm getting all the pixels colored on which the mouse is, and the image doesn't seem to update too. When I walk over, all I get is a black label (the image is wiped out) and ALL the green pixels where I have been with my mouse.
**However it should color ONLY the current pixel ON the existing image, and then it should refresh to the next position.** Here is the function I have implemented for this:

```
   QPoint current = event->pos(); 
   QPoint localPos = ui->label_image_2->mapFromParent(current);
   if(ui->label_image_2->rect().contains((localPos))){
       image.setPixel(localPos.x(),localPos.y(), qRgb(0,255,0));
       ui->label_image_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
```

When I walk through the image on label_2, the current position ON the image should be marked green. Am I missing something, or is my general approach wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does your `image` variable come from? It doesn't have the correct contents. You were probably setting some image on the label, but instead you should set that image on the `image` member variable, and use *that* to set on the label.

Comment: I was able to fix it, turned out, I had declared image as a global QImage variable, however I had called the function as ```draw(image,,...)```. Calling it as ```draw(&image,,...)``` fixed the problem!